# How can I make a change language shortcut for voice recognition in android 2.3.4?

Tags: languages, voice-command, voice-recognition

I have a Samsung Galaxy S2 Phone, I work in English, Spanish and French, and constantly have to change from one language to the other, making a shortcut to change the language of the voice-recognition would make this the perfect, perfect phone, I would prefer to dictate my email and WhatsApp messages instead of typing them all the time, but going in to the home screen/menu/voice-recognition settings etc... just defeats the purpose... it takes more steps than to just type it...

By default It should be that: when I swipe to change the language of the Gingerbread keyboard it should also change the language of the voice recognition...

Please help, anyone... I would gladly pay for any app or script that solves this... does anyone know where can I find this?

Comment: Does not exactly solve your problem, but might provide at least an easier work-around: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20599/is-it-posible-to-change-the-locale-of-my-device/28245#28245

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you hold the microphone icon it brings up a menu that allows you to change those settings. It may be the comma icon on your phone however. Previous versions allowed you to swipe the keyboard. Otherwise there are many alternative keyboards you can download from the Android Play Store.