# Is it posible to change the locale of my device?

Tags: settings, languages, locale

In my Android phone when I go to `Settings -> Language and Keyboard Settings -> Select Language` I see "Locale" as the title on the top row and see that only few languages are listed. I suspect its because of this "Locale" setting.

Where I can change it so that all supported languages will be listed? Under `Settings -> Language & Keyboard` I don't see a "Locale" option.

Comment: What phone do you have and what version of Android is it runnning? That may well affect the answers.

Comment: I don't think "Locale" is a separate setting anywhere. It just looks like the list title/header to me. This also sounds like it may be a duplicate of [How do I add a new language?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/15361/981)

Comment: android version is 2.3.5 . Does the language list depend on teh android version or is it divide by the mobile manufacturer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The keyboard settings shows all supported languages no matter the locale of the device, so if a language is not listed than it's not supported. A good alternative is [AnysoftKeyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.menny.android.anysoftkeyboard); you can download language packs for it.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change locale settings on your device, the [Set Locale and Language](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bruce.setlocale) app<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEvXh.jpg)</sup> might prove helpful as well. [Locale-Einstellung](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.locale.setlocale) looks almost the same. [MoreLocale 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.c_lis.ccl.morelocale)<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOGnA.png)</sup> might offer an alternative, as it also allows to create custom locales -- which is also supported by [Custom Locale](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mhoffs.customlocale)<sup>[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRHTp.jpg)</sup>.

[image: Set Locale] [image: MoreLocale2] [image: Custom Locale]

With [Any Locale](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.easyjp.apps.localesetter)<sup>[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd7cN.jpg)</sup> switching the locale can be as easy as tapping a widget -- as it is with [LocaleSwitch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aokabi.android.localeswitch)<sup>[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpF7w.jpg)</sup> or the [Language Picker Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.gnvo.langpicker)<sup>[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxzdV.jpg)</sup>.

[image: Any Locale] [image: LocaleSwitch] [image: Language Picker]

Also very nice: [Raygional](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.raygional)<sup>[7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4CwI.jpg)</sup>. And there are probably many more to chose from...

[image: Raygional]

Answer (score 1):

Here was how I changed them on my Google Pixel 7:

- Open "Settings"
- Choose "System"
- Choose "Languages"
- Choose "System Languages"
- "Add a language" (I added "Español")
- Drag that language to the top using the drag icon (two lines) on the right

My system switched to Spanish, although bits were still English. I bet if I restarted the phone they would all switch to Spanish.

Then finding that setting again was not so easy for me! (I hadn't written down how I got there, and now it was all in Spanish.)