# Can I change system locale by command?

Tags: localization, tasker, automation

For some reason I need to change system locale temporarily.
Can I change system locale using some command? or script?
So that i can run it with tasker's built-in shell.

Comment: Couldn't figure that one out -- but maybe [this answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20599/is-it-posible-to-change-the-locale-of-my-device/28245#28245) may help you meanwhile for a work-around on faster switching locales.

Comment: @Izzy: Now there's an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDMsImNvbS5pbnRhbmdpYmxlb2JqZWN0LnNlY3VyZXNldHRpbmdzLnBsdWdpbiJd) plugin. Parts of it require root, so I'm not sure whether this will work if you're un-rooted. It works perfectly for me, but I'm rooted.

Comment: FYI, this is not working for me when I'm un-rooted.