# How to change System Language in Android?

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, languages

I bought the HTC One from China. I have rooted it succesfully and removed all bloatwares in chinese language. 
It has english language but it says "English (China)" 
How can I install any other english like english(India) or english (UK)

The problem is still when someone calls me its shows some chinese charcter . Even in call logs it shows the same.

I installed the Morelocale2 but when I change ot to English India. it says NA.
But can be done? Please help. I searched on internet too but didnt find any solution for this.

Comment: Having used the 'languages' tag: did you check [its most frequented questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/languages?sort=frequent)? There you can find e.g.: [Is it posible to change the locale of my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/20599/16575) (which might be helpful for your last question). To get rid of that Chinese remains altogether, you might need to flash a different ROM.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy. This clears that I will never able to remove that characters :(

Comment: Why? No custom ROMs for that device?

Comment: Nope . There are but I dont know how to ? This HTC model only available in China . so all roms are available on Chinese Forums. Very difficult :(.

Comment: Not having that device, I never checked. But you might want to check with [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Comment: Thanks @Izzy. I am posting a new question reagrding ROM installation. Here is the link http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48961/how-do-i-install-the-custom-rom-with-boot-img-inside