# How do I install the custom ROM with boot.img inside?

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, rom

I have found a custom ROM in Chinese forums for mY HTC ONE SU (t528w) model.

The ROM is zipped and the folders look like below image

[image]

I have no idea to install this ROM. Could anybody please guide me to install this. I dont know how and where to place the boot.img. I have successfully unlocked my bootloader and mobile is rooted too.

Thanks

Comment: You don't want to open it and look at it.  You may want to flash the entire zip file using the appropriate PC software for your device, or possibly from your device's Recovery.  I am not familiar with HTC devices unfortunately so I can't give you specifics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the place where you downloaded the ROM from, it usually contains installation instructions. In most cases, these ROMs use the `update.zip` mechanism of the recovery mode, as Matthew mentioned. You might need a custom recovery (see [clockworkmod](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod) and [twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp) and their tag-wikis, [clockworkmod](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/clockworkmod/info) resp. [twrp](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/twrp/info), for examples).

The process then usually is as follows:

1. copy the `.zip` to your SDCard
2. boot into [recovery-mode](/questions/tagged/recovery-mode)
3. select to "apply update from SDCard"
4. navigate to and select your `.zip`
5. let it flash
6. go back to the main menu and select to "reboot device"